# how to access the current controller name inside my Razor view jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following script , that is being used inside multiple views:-

```
 $("#ChoiceTag, #ChoiceName").each(function () {
            $(this).change(function () {
                if ($("#ChoiceName").prop("checked")) {
                    $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Firewall/LoadCSName")",
                    function (CSData) {
                        var select = $("#GeneralCSID");
                        select.empty();
                        select.append($('<option/>', {
                            value: "",
                            text: "Select Name..."
                        }));
                        $.each(CSData, function (index, itemData) {

                            select.append($('<option/>', {
                                value: itemData.Value,
                                text: itemData.Text
                            }));
                            select.val('@Model.CSIT360ID');
                    });
                });
            }
```

the script is exactly the same for all the views except for the controller name inside the following statement:-

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Firewall/LoadCSName")",
```

so i am looking to move the above script and add it inside a separate .js file, and then reference this script , but i have the following two question:-

1. if i move the script to the script folder i need to dynamically reference the current controller name to build the URL, so is this possible
2. can i still reference the viewbag as i am currently doing ..
   Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move your Javascript into an external file you can't use your Razor syntax. Therefore, `@Url.Content("~/Firewall/LoadCSName")` will not resolve.

To overcome this add this to your view

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var AppPath = '@Url.Content("~/")'</script>
```

and reference it in your script like this

```
$.getJSON(AppPath + "Controller/Action")
```

Regarding the viewbag. Just put the viewbags value in a variable as shown above and your external file can reference it.

Hope this helps

**Update**

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var AppPath = '@Url.Content("~/")';
        var SomeValue = '@Model.CSIT360ID';
        var ControllerName = "Firewall/LoadCSName";
    </script>
    <!--Move this to an external File-->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#ChoiceTag, #ChoiceName").each(function () {
            $(this).change(function() {
                if ($("#ChoiceName").prop("checked")) {

                    $.getJSON(AppPath + ViewBagValue), function(CSData) {
                            var select = $("#GeneralCSID");
                            select.empty();
                            select.append($('<option/>', {
                                value: "",
                                text: "Select Name..."
                            }));

                            $.each(CSData, function(index, itemData) {

                                select.append($('<option/>', {
                                    value: itemData.Value,
                                    text: itemData.Text
                                }));

                                select.val(SomeValue);
                            });
                            //end each

                    });
                }
            });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Update 2**

This is how you could reference the controller in the url.content

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var AppPath = '@Url.Content("~/" + HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"])'
</script>
```

Comment: but where i will be referencing the javaScript , u added the<script> without mentioning the name ?

Comment: another question why are u referencing the @Url.Content("~/") inside the razor view ? and what will this return ?

Comment: Im referencing @Url.Content in the view because the razor tag can be rendered here. This will return the relative path. Your external js file can reference this and use it to create relative urls to your controllers. Hope this helps.

Comment: @johnG I've updated my answer. Hopefully the code should make it easier to understand

Comment: the only thing i need to ask is there a way to dynamically reference the current controller name (which is  firewall) instead of manually writing it Firewall as in "var ControllerName = "Firewall/LoadCSName";"

Comment: Not in an external JS file, no. But you can dynamically add it to the view like this var ControllerName = "@HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()"

Comment: but not sure how i can refernce this var inside the Url.Content ?

Answer (score 2):

you can get the controller name this way:

```
   @{
string controllerName = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: but not sure how i will be referencing the view-bag values

Comment: and can i use your above code, if i am writting a pure javaScript? or do u mean to add this inside a partial view ?

Comment: what i think ViewBag values should also be accessible in script file but not sure as never did like that

Comment: I am afraid you cannot do it in js file, you have to add your script in master layout

Comment: or can i add my scripts inside a partial view and render the partial view inside the related Views ? as i want to avoid adding these scripts inside the master page, since i only need them in around 10 views, while my system contains more that 200 views ...

Comment: i mean is it a bad practice to have a partial view that contains Scripts only, as this will give me the opportunity to access the viewbag values and also re-using the scripts on multiple views ..

Comment: you can make functions in js file with parameters and call them from view by passing values from ViewBag

Comment: you have a method in external js file: ``fuction doalert(a) { alert(a);}`` now in view : call it thi way: ``doalert('@ViewBag.SomeValue');``

Answer (score 0):

To access controller name from view use

```
@{
    ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
}
```

To access controller instance one can use as follow

```
@{
    (HomeController)ViewContext.Controller
}
```

Comment: This gives me a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0):

One (slightly hacky) to make the current controller name accessible to JS would be to burn it into a global or namespaced variable assignment in the layout.

```
<script>
var app = window.app || {}

app.currentController = "@HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().toLower()";

</script>
```

Alternatively, a common way I work is to add classnames of the current controller and action to the body tag, to assist in DOM based routing in any javascript.